# compare with properties file values with local variable in dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

In below dataweave code, comparision is not working properly for me.

Properties file key and value as below :
`domain=Sales Domain, Retail Domain`

Dataweave code :

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var test = 'Sales Domain'
---
{
result: if(upper(test) != (upper(Mule::p('domain'))))  "Not equal" else ("equal")
}
```

Could you please help on this ?

Comment: This script should be returning "Not equal".  If you want it to return "equal" consider using  the `contains` function instead of `!=` ... https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-contains

Answer (score 1):

The property domain contains the string `Sales Domain, Retail Domain`. The comparison with the variable test which contain the string `Sales Domain`. Obviously both strings are different, even converting to uppercase (`upper()`).

If you want to check if one string contains the other you could use the [`contains()`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-contains#contains2) function instead.

In DataWeave there is not a not-equal operator to compare the values. You can use the [`not`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-operators#logical_operators) operator to negate the result of an expression.

For example:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var test = 'Sales Domain'
---
{
     result: if(upper(Mule::p('domain')) contains upper(test)) "contains" else "not contains"
}
```

Comment: could you please help to write the dataweave code and share if possible ?

Comment: I tried with this.     result: if(upper(test) contains upper(Mule::p('domain')))  "contain" else ("not contain")         but not working....

Comment: When you said it is not working, do you mean the comparison is returning false? That is to be expected because the smaller string can not ever contain the larger string. You should see if the larger string contains the smaller string.

Comment: Yes,  result: if(upper(Mule::p('domain'))contains upper(test) )  "contain" else ("not contain").        this is working.... Your previous comment is this right 'comparison the larger string contains the smaller string' ?

Comment: and can we add NOT contains condition  in  this code.   if(upper(Mule::p('domain'))contains upper(test) ) "contain" else ("not contain").   If yes, can you please modify my code and send it back ?

Comment: use the `not` operator to negate the result of the contains expression. ie `not(upper....contains ...)`

Comment: Not is not required, I fixed the example.

Comment: It's a good practice to apply the parentheses after the not operator. It will apply to everything to the right. There is now also a ! operator, but it has a higher precedence than not. not true and false is the same as `not ( true and false )` returns `true`.` !true and true` is the same as `(false) and false` which `false`.

Comment: I got the answer. Thanks.